# Append profile to other spring-profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I can configure activeProfiles in tests for spring-boot with

```
@ActiveProfiles("mynewone")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FooTest extends AbstractIntTest
```

I do not understand the spring-documentation how to add my profile "mynewone" to already running profiles. If I configure it it like above, only "mynewone" is active.

Answer (score 0):

Use `spring.profiles.include=mynewone` in the application properties file.

Comment: That is possible. But I want to programmaticaly add an active profile. I write "mynewone" all configured active-profiles are overwritten.